Query Across Servers in PostgreSQL
Is is possible to query across servers in PostgreSQL? For example, by using an INSERT INTO query to insert table data from a table in one server to another? If so, would the query look roughly like the following:
INSERT INTO [destination table]
SELECT *
FROM [source server].[source schema].[source table]
?
I tried running this query, and received the following error "cross-database references are not implemented"

Yes, using postgres_fdw. With other foreign data wrappers or dblink you can also run queries against other databases or even files.

Yes, using postgres_fdw. Example from the doc:
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER foreign_server
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (host '192.83.123.89', port '5432', dbname 'foreign_db');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR local_user
        SERVER foreign_server
        OPTIONS (user 'foreign_user', password 'password');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_table (
        id integer NOT NULL,
        data text
)
        SERVER foreign_server
        OPTIONS (schema_name 'some_schema', table_name 'some_table');

Once that's done, you can query it like it's local, but the data will be routed to/from the other database. E.g., if you insert into foreign_table, the data will get inserted into the table on the other database, and when you select, it'll be read from it.
Native postgres_fdw is a bit more advanced than other foreign data wrappers and it'll be able to decide if data necessary to perform a join between a local and foreign table should be moved from here to there, or the other way around, among other pg-to-pg interoperability optimisations.
With other foreign data wrappers or dblink you can also run queries against other databases or even files, but that typically boils down to mapping SQL to file-format-specific I/O, or forwarding queries to other DBs, either raw, or with some attempt to translate between SQL dialects.
